# how can i convert DataFrame into DataSet in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, r

i am using R.Net. in that i have done some database connection using R.Net in that i am getting the result in DataFrame format i need to convert it into DataSet

here is my code:

```
    REngine.SetDllDirectory("@C:\Program Files\R\R-2.12.0\bin\i386")
    engine = REngine.CreateInstance("RDotNet")
    engine.EagerEvaluate("library(RODBC);")
    engine.EagerEvaluate("con <- odbcConnect(dsn='rdsn', uid = 'sa', pwd = 'surya');")


    cmdStr = SELECT DISTINCT Investment.InvestmentTypeCode,InvestmentTypeDescription,     SortID  FROM Investment,InvestmentTypeDef WHERE(Investment.InvestmentTypeCode = InvestmentTypeDef.InvestmentTypeCode) ORDER BY SortID

   engine.EagerEvaluate("frm <- sqlQuery(con, '" + cmdStr + "');")

   engine.GetSymbol("frm").AsDataFrame()
```

if any one knows plz help me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not built-in functionality in R.Net or in the .NET Framework which can do that. But you can create and fill DataSets programmatically. So you will have to write your own conversion code.

See:
[Creating A DataSet Programmatically](http://bytes.com/topic/asp-net/answers/324672-creating-dataset-programmatically)

Answer (score 1):

I recently had to convert a RDataFrame to a standard DataTable in C# - I'm assuming all the columns contain doubles:

```
public static DataTable RDataFrameToDataSet(DataFrame resultsMatrix) {

        var dt = new DataTable();
        var columns = new DataColumn[resultsMatrix.ColumnCount];

        for (int i = 0; i < resultsMatrix.ColumnCount; i++) {
            columns[i] = new DataColumn(resultsMatrix.ColumnNames[i], typeof(double));
        }

        dt.Columns.AddRange(columns);

        for (int y = 0; y < resultsMatrix.RowCount; y++) {
            var dr = dt.NewRow();
            for (int x = 0; x < resultsMatrix.ColumnCount; x++) {
                try {
                    dr[x] = resultsMatrix[y, x];
                }
                catch (Exception ex) {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                }
            }
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        }

        return dt;
    }
```